# Can somebody please create tags for the major Australian parties

Tags: discussion

If i want to ask questions about the major parties in australia there is no tag could somebody please create them.  Here are the websites

http://www.alp.org.au/
https://www.liberal.org.au/
greens.org.au

Comment: there's a tag for `Australia` and there's a tag for `parties`.  Do you need tags for the individual parties?

Comment: @SamIam eventually will, ok maybe not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags cannot be created in isolation.

If you have questions about the major parties in Australia, post them using existing tags (e.g. [australia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia)). If more specific tags are indeed necessary, the community will add them eventually.